# How can I add "#" in my url when using html.ActionLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, actionlink

This is my html.ActionLink:

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Comment", "Comment", new { id = item.NewsId, title = item.Title + "#disqus_thread" })
```

it gives me following url:

```
http://localhost:62394/Home/Comment/5008/Iran%20women%20barred%20from%20presidency%23disqus_thread
```

instead of  `"#"` it generates `"%23"`

How can I make sure it becomes like this:

`

```
http://localhost:62394/Home/Comment/5008/Iran%20women%20barred%20from%20presidency#disqus_thread
```

Any kind of help is appreciate alot!

Comment: How can i do same thing in MVC controller class when i am passion RedirectToAction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:-

Convert ActionLink to string use URLDecode and change it to render it as Html.Raw.

```
@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Html.ActionLink("Comment", "Comment"
, new { id =  
 item.NewsId, title = item.Title + "#disqus_thread" }).ToString()))
```

Answer (score 5):

You should use [Url.Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504960%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) like this:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Comment", new { id = item.NewsId, title = item.Title })#disqus_thread">Comment</a>
```

I believe it's simpler, cleaner and **safer**.

Answer (score 0):

when we pass special characters in query string of the requested url, it may cause error unless they are properly encoded. These special characters can be handled by using the **Hexadecimal Value** of the characters instead of the characters themselves.

so instead of using **#**

```
@Html.ActionLink("Comment", "Comment", new { id = item.NewsId, title = item.Title + "#disqus_thread" })
```

use Hexadecimal Value **%23**

```
@Html.ActionLink("Comment", "Comment", new { id = item.NewsId, title = item.Title + "%23disqus_thread" })
```

i hope this may help you..

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue but it was in a DevExpress Grid Link.  This was the only way I was able to resolve it.

`@Html.ActionLink("Comment", "Comment", new { id = item.NewsId, title = item.Title + "#disqus_thread" }).ToString().Replace("%23", "#")`

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have to create URL that point to Bootsrap 4 Tab that has two tabs only.

```
@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.UrlDecode(@Html.ActionLink("My second TAB", "Index#second", "Home", null, new { @class = "btn-link" }).ToString()))
```

So final URL will look likes

> http://localhost:62959/Home/Index#second

Answer (score -1):

You should decode the URL before inserting it:

```
@HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Html.ActionLink("Comment", "Comment", new { id = item.NewsId, title = item.Title + "#disqus_thread" }))
```

Comment: Hmm its not working I am recieving 2 Errors The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(string)' has some invalid arguments. Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Web.Mvc.MvcHtmlString' to 'string'